# SwiftUi Preview is not showing up

Tags: xcode, swiftui

**Error being shown**: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gv7G.png)

**Solutions I tried:**

1. Restarting the project
2. Refreshing the preview
3. Changing the Simulator target.
4. Tried to have the Simulation run on the Simulator used in Storyboard scenario but wasn't successful. It might be due to me not having more knowledge on it.

**Code I used:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextBootcamp: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World! This is the skillful bootcamp program. I am really enjoying this course.")
            //.baselineOffset(10.0)
            .frame(width: 290, height: 100, alignment: .leading)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)      
           //.font(.body)
           // .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}
struct TextBootcamp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextBootcamp()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my end. I am using Xcode 14.0.1. Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Command-Option-Enter or To-right  menu/Canvas